# How can I access DataGridView from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In the form1 i create a datagridview that fill rows with database.
in the form2 i want to show the user the specific row of datagridview from form1.
specific row is chosen by user !!!
i set my datagridview in public modifier and that is my form 2 code:

```
form1 parentsell = new form1();
string selecteduser = parentsell.propertydatagrid.Rows[selectedrowindex].Cells[72].Value.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(selecteduser);
```

thats no error when program is build but after run that give me an Err.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: i try this code too but same error...

Comment: string selecteduser = parentsell.propertydatagrid.Rows[0].Cells[72].Value.ToString();

Comment: We need to see more code to help. The error is basically telling you that the selected cell is out of range (doesn't exist). My guess is that you're not populating the `DataGridView` until after `form1` is shown (or even later, perhaps). Because you're not showing `parentsell` after you create it, the grid is probably not getting filled. But, as I said, it's hard to know without seeing more of your code. Try showing `parentsell` after instantiating it.

Comment: Also, consider using a design pattern like MVP. Accessing data across forms is not ideal. Something like MVP would consolidate the business logic into one place and make it easier to access data across UI elements.

Comment: See my two form project.  You need to use an instance of the form and make sure the form doesn't close (hide instead) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Your problem is that in your code for form2 you are creating a new instance of form1 (`form1 parentsell = new form1()`), which is never shown, has no data and therefore nothing selected, rather than getting a reference to the pre-existing form1.  How are you opening form2?  If you do it from form1, then in the constructor of form2, you need a reference to the calling form1, which you pass using the `this` special word.

Answer (score 0):

So, you probably using lookup Form, you need to pass value by reference, and easiest way is to crate class User like this:

```
public Class User
{
   public string name {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can make instance of that object in main Form, like this

```
User user = new User();
form1 parentsell = new form1(user);
parentsell.ShowDialog(); // This will open another form and wait you to finish work
MessageBox.Show(user.name);
```

In form1 you need to create another constructor and instance of User

```
User user;
public form1(User user)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.user = user;
}
```

Now you need some button that will say "Ok, I found this user, now take him and close this form" like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
   user.name = ...; //find your user, DGV.selectedRows[0].Cells[somehing].Value.ToString(); I think it's like this...
   this.Close();
}
```

And you should get your selected user in Main form

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach:

Add this line to the other form(e.g. Form2) where you want to access the datagridview:

```
public static DataGridView view { get; set; }
```

Then go to the form(e.g. Form1) that contains the DataGridView(e.g. dataGridView1) that you want to access.
Add this line to that form:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
       Form2.view.Rows.Add(row.Cells["Column1"].Value);
       Form2.view.Rows.Add(row.Cells["Column2"].Value);
}
```

Add a textbox(e.g. textBox1) for the user to add the index of the required row and get it in a new datagridview(e.g. dataGridView2) in this way:

```
dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView2.Rows.Add(view.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)].Cells["Column1"].Value, view.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)].Cells["Column2"].Value)
```

> Remember that a datagridview row index starts from '0'.
>
> Also remember to add two columns to the dataGridView2 before running the code.

---

You can also directly call data from the database to the required form instead of fetching it from another datagridview.